# How to synchronize two videos with variable frame rates?

Tags: video, opencv, video-processing, pyglet

I have many video file pairs that is taken with two network cameras in a room. Because of the bandwidth utilization, video files have variable frame rates. As far as I understand, if we mark the frames on a timeline it is something like this:

[image: variable frame rates]

I want to synchronize these two videos. By synchronizing I mean, filling in the gaps such that for a given frame in a video there is a corresponding frame in the other video. In the end I want two have two videos like this:

[image]

I have thought about converting both videos to 25 fps using a converter tool, although I will have redundant frame pairs they will be synchronized. However, I have information associated with each frame for all videos, I won't be able to know the association after conversion.

I think I need to do this programmatically so that I can keep the information associated with each frame accordingly.

So far I have tried OpenCV, `VideoCapture` property `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` gives me the frame number, not the millisecond of the frame. Even if it gave me correct values, `VideoWriter` does not support variable frame rate. MATLAB refuses to read my video files because it does not support the codec, which is MJPEG (motion jpeg). I have been able to read frame # and corresponding millisecond using [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) in Python. But it is only decoder, I still don't have anything to write to a video file like "This is frame #12 and this should be exactly at 1.76 secs of the video".

I am looking for the simplest way to achieve this, language, tool does not matter. Windows based solutions are appreciated. Thank you very much for your answers.

**PS.** I don't mind the output format, I would prefer a loseless format though.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is to convert both to the same fps (let's say 25), then match them. ffmpeg is a great tool for this. Check this blog post for more details http://www.hdslr-cinema.com/news/workflow/convert-between-framerates/

But probably it will duplicate frames to cover the empty slots. If this doesn't cover your requirements, you should look into time interpolation - interpolate pixels between frames. But this is a lot of work. ffmpeg solution is a 5-minute task, interpolation may mean to read and implement some academic papers.

Note that there may be some dedicated tools for interpolation, but I do not know about them. It is worth investigating.

Comment: I don't mind interpolating on my own, as I told there are associated information with frames like (#1, info1), (#2, info2) so if I convert both of them using a tool I won't know how to match between previous associations and new ones. I will check ffmpeg library out.